# HQL: Join with nested select

Tags: sql, hql

I am trying to achieve this query with HQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Gift g 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT det.GiftId FROM ItemDetails det WHERE det.Active=1) r1 ON g.GiftId=r1.GiftId 
WHERE r1.GiftId IS null
```

This query gives me what I need in SQL Server but I need it to work in HQL.  I have tried this:

```
SELECT distinct g
FROM (SELECT det.gift FROM ItemDetails det WHERE det.active=1) as r
RIGHT OUTER JOIN r.gift g
WHERE r.gift IS null
```

GiftId is a foreignkey in ItemDetails that references a row in Gift.  I think this is not working because the nested query is in the FROM clause but I am not sure how to reword it.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:  Final working version..

```
   SELECT distinct g
   FROM Gift g 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (from ItemDetails det where det.active=1 and det.gift=g.id)
```

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to query?

Comment: I have a table of gifts and a table of item that are included in a gift.  The itemdetail table has a fk that refers to a giftId.  If a user chooses to take away a gift the gift status is set to cancelled and the itemdetail active flag is set to 0.  I am trying to query the database to get a list of gifts that do not have any more active items.

Answer (score 1):

Does this version work?

```
SELECT g.*
FROM Gift g
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from ItemDetails det
                  where det.Active = 1 and
                        det.GiftId = g.GiftId
                 );
```

You can also do this as a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM Gift g LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ItemDetails det 
     on det.Active = 1 and g.GiftId = r1.GiftId 
WHERE det.GiftId IS null;
```

You don't need the subquery, because you can just move the filtering condition into the `on` clause.

Comment: not exists was a good idea.  I'm using a modified version of this and it compiles unlike it did before.  I would confirm it, but I'm now stuck on a different error I have to fix before I can test this.  I will get back to you :D

Comment: Ok, it works!  I'm putting the final version in an edit up top.  Thanks, I would up vote that but it seems I don't have enough reputation yet.